# Azure LogicApp Execute SQL Query (V2) has no body in the output with CTE in Query

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, azure-logic-apps

I usually use stored procedures but in this situation I have to use a query and while the examples below are not the one I am running they do replicate the issue.

This simple select returns exactly what you would expect.  A resultset with table1.

[image]

This select including the CTE runs successfully but the output has not body.  The query itself runs against the database without issue so is syntactically correct for us.  I can't find anything saying there is a known problem - has anyone else experienced this?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:  Flow diagram included showing that dynamic content not even showing.

[image]

Comment: I am able to get the Output body as well. Can you share your flow diagram please?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin - sure - added to edit.  The simplest of the simple.  We do this all the time, first time this has happened.  I checked another that uses SQL Query instead of Execute Procedure.  No issue.  Completely baffled.

I have deleted this logic app and started again too.

Comment: Which action you are using? I am using Execute a SQL query (V2) action and able to see the [output](https://i.imgur.com/hvLHF1s.png)

Comment: Yeah that is what I am using.

Comment: Raise it with Microsoft is my advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the Output body using `Execute a SQL query (V2)` action in logic app.

I have used the query given by you in my workflow.

```sql
WITH X AS (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Invoice])
SELECT  TOP  10  *  FROM [dbo].[InvoiceItem] JOIN X ON x.Id=InvoiceId
```

[image]

Settings of `Execute a SQL query (V2)` looks like below-

[image]

I am able to get the Output body.

[image]
[image]

I am able to see the fields in dynamic content too.

[image]

Comment: This is nuts, makes no sense

Comment: Have you tried creating a fresh logic app instance?

Comment: Try freshing or loading the page, if the issue still persists I would suggest you to check with the product team

Comment: @LeeAlderdice Did you manage to get the output body?

Comment: Sadly no - properly frustrating.

Comment: @LeeAlderdice please raise it with the product team